# Given the following code , under Eclipse ,I get a type mismatch error :cannot convert from java.lang.reflect.Type to android.renderscript.Type

Tags: android

cannot convert from java.lang.reflect.Type to android.renderscript.Type:

```
protected void OnPostExecute(Object result) {
            String data = (String) result;
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type typ =new TypeToken<EmpModel[]>() {
            }.getType();
            EmpModel[] emp =(EmpModel[])gson.fromJson(data,typ);
            ListView list =getListView();
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<EmpModel>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.activity_list_item,emp));              
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the import statement for `Type`.

It's probably  `java.lang.reflect.Type` - change it to `android.renderscript.Type`

Answer (score 0):

You might have imported wrong line

Change this :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type
```

To  this:

```
import android.renderscript.Type
```

Hope it helps ツ

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this

```
java.lang.reflect.Type typ =new  TypeToken<EmpModel[]>() {}.getType();
```

Comment: this what others trying to say u